# STR_TO_DATE for different formats

Tags: mysql

Quick question: I have this two type of values in my varchar column:

29/04/2010 22.04

or

29/04/2010 22:04

is there a way to set alternatives for the hour and minute separator since it could be `.` or `:`?

Comment: It is better to use DATETIME data type. In your case (VARCHAR type) you could replace '.' with ':' to avoid these alternatives.

Comment: Can't do that. The client fills up that table, I just have to map that value to another datetime field.

Comment: Replace '.' with ':' in SELECT statement, or write a view. Also you can create a trigger on your table and change inserted values.